# Kivy Label text fade in

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make some text in a label fade in using the animation tool in kivy but I can't get it to work and I found NOTHING on the internet to help anywhere.
Heres the code:

.py:

```
class TestScreen(Screen):
    def animate (self):
        anim = Animate(opacity=1, duration=2)
        anim.start(self.lbl)
```

.kv

```
<TestScreen>
    lbl: label
    Label
        id: label
        text: "Welcome"
```

Answer (score 2):

- change `Animate` with `Animation`
- `opacity=1` means label is visible, what you want is `opacity=0`
- you should call `animate` function
  somewhere

Here's fully working example (Python 2.7):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
__metaclass__ = type

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.animation import Animation


Builder.load_string(b'''
<RootWidget>:
    lbl: label
    Label
        id: label
        text: "Welcome"
''')


class RootWidget(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.animate()

    def animate(self):
        anim = Animation(opacity=0, duration=2)
        anim.start(self.lbl)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't get why we need to put that def __init__ thing XD

Comment: @HussamAl-hassan `animate` - is just a method of your class. It need to be called somewhere to start animation. You can call it wherever you want: on `__init__` (on widget creation), on some button pressing, on some element click ... - anywhere you want.

Comment: It's giving me an error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: @HussamAl-hassan did you run it with Python 2.7? Did you copy whole code exactly as it's above? Can you provide full stack trace that comes with error message?